# Proof on a particular property of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory

There is a theorem that states:

$$|a^k| =\frac{n}{\gcd (n,k)}$$

The author begin by stating we are to prove that if d is a positive divisor of n, then

$$|a^d|=\frac{n}{d}$$

Where did this came about? Could someone fill me in on the leap in argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is quite simple actually. Take $ d = \gcd (n, k) $

$$  (a^k)^{\frac nd } = (a^n)^{\frac k d} = e \tag{1}$$
$$  (a^k)^r = e  \implies a^{kr} = e \implies n \ \mid kr \implies \dfrac n d \ \mid r \cdot \dfrac k d \implies   \dfrac n d \ \mid r \tag 2$$

The last implication is due to the fact that $ \gcd \left({ \dfrac n d, \dfrac k d}\right) = 1 $ and Euclid's Lemma.

The claims follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$

Comment: I'm not sure if it follows that $n\mid kr $, take for instance $\mathbb {Z}/4 \mathbb {Z} $. Then $2^2=e $ but $4\nmid 2$. I think it only works if $a $ generates the group. (Or in general if the order of $a$ is $n$)

Comment: @Uncountable I'm pretty sure OP is talking about a cyclic group, $(a)$ whose order is $n$.

Comment: Edit: figured out

Comment: @Ishfaaq I have to ask this: How do you know n/d is prime? Also, how do you decide which integer does n/d divides?

Comment: If $d = \gcd(n, k) $ then $d = n x +ky$ for some integers $ x $ and $y$. Dividing this by $d$ we get $ \dfrac n d \cdot x + \dfrac k d \cdot y = 1 $ which establishes $ \gcd (\dfrac n d, \dfrac k d) = 1  $. Then we apply Euclid's Lemma.

Answer (score 0):

$ (a^k)^j = 1 \iff n\mid kj\iff n\mid nj,kj \iff n\mid (nj,kj)= (n,k)j \iff n/(n,k)\mid j$