# a question on gcd of 2 rational integers being 1 and euclid's lemma

Tags: euclidean-algorithm, gcd-and-lcm

I had a problem with a proof on group and a poster aided me with the proof.
But I had problems understanding the final implication relates to GCD and Euclid's lemma:

$$(a^k)^r=e \Rightarrow a^{kr} = e \Rightarrow n | kr \Rightarrow \frac n d | r \cdot \frac k d \Rightarrow \frac n d | r .$$

The last implication is due to the fact that $\gcd \Big( \frac n d, \frac k d \Big) = 1$ and Euclid's lemma.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are $k,r,n,d\,$ in the context?

Comment: e is the identity element. k, r, n and d are all integers.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307664/proof-on-a-particular-property-of-cyclic-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{n}{d}\mid r\cdot\frac{k}{d}$ means exactly that any prime that divides $n/d$ also divides $r\cdot k/d$.

Here is where we use Euclid's lemma: if a prime divides the product $r\cdot\frac{k}{d}$, then it must divide one of the factors. But $\gcd(n/d,k/d)=1$, so *they* don't share any prime factors. Therefore, the prime must divide $r$. This gives $\frac{n}{d}\mid r$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ n\mid nr,kr\,\Rightarrow\,n\mid (nr,kr) = (\overbrace{n,k}^{\large d})r\ $ i.e. $\ n\mid dr,\ $ so $\ n/d\mid r $

This proof uses more general gcd properties (e.g. the gcd distributive law) vs. Euclid's Lemma. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) for a few proofs of Euclid's Lemma using these and other properties.

Comment: Haha, the irony! I found your post in the low quality posts queue... Please stop producing low quality content! :))

Comment: @AlexM. Apparently robots are not fans of "proofs without words". So much for the Turing Test...

Comment: @BillDubuque Very helpful. Probably a good  time to look through past notes.

Comment: @AlexM.How is Bill producing low quality content? I found this to be helpful.

Comment: @Mathematicing Alex is joking. The SE bot flagged the first version of my answer as low quality (probably because it was so concise and had few words).